# Process a form called in a template literal

Tags: javascript

I have a program that makes an html table using a json file. I want to make a form to be able to select how many of each item i want to add to my shopping cart. The table is called using template literals, but i feel like the form doesn't register with those. Whenever i run the form, it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null, hence i feel like the form hasn't registered in the html document.

I have already tried to wrap my function in a window.onload but it still doesn't work.

Here is my javascript file:

```
//load JSON file
var articles = ""
var txt = ""
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    articles = xmlhttp.responseText;
    processArticles(articles);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","../articles.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processArticles(articles) {
  txt = JSON.parse(articles);

  var tableStart = `
    <h2>Liste des articles</h2>
    <form id="formtable">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Prix-Retour</th>
        <th>Quantitée maximale</th>
        <th>Projet</th>
        <th>Quantitée</th>
      </tr>`;

  var tableEnd = `
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>`;

  function articlesTemplate(txt) {
    return `
        <tr>
          <td>${txt.ID}</td>
          <td>${txt.Article }</td>
          <td>${txt.Prix}</td>
          <td>${txt.PrixRetour}</td>
          <td>${txt.QuantiteeMaximale}</td>
          <td>${txt.Projet}</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5"></td>
        </tr>
    `;
  }

  let mctxt=txt.filter(value=>
    value.Projet=="mc");
    document.getElementById("tablemc").innerHTML = `
      ${tableStart}
      ${mctxt.map(articlesTemplate).join("")}
      ${tableEnd}
      `;
    ;
}

window.onload=function(){

  var form = document.getElementById('formtable');

  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("HI");
    console.log(form.quantity.value);
    form.reset();
  };
}
```

i have a div in my html file which

I want to be able to see the amount of times each item is selected, but right now my form doesn't seem to register in my html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see in your code, the window loads before the request is received, and hence has not yet created a table of the ID table form.

You might want to read up on [Asynchronous and Synchronous XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)  to understand why your code doesn't work

If you removed the code inside the `window.onload` and run it after `processArticles()` has been called, your code *should* work fine

Example:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    articles = xmlhttp.responseText;
    processArticles(articles);

    var form = document.getElementById('formtable');

    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("HI");
      console.log(form.quantity.value);
      form.reset();
    };
  }
};
```

Now remove all of your `window.onload` code

Comment: Thanks for the help, this helped me with a similar issue!

Comment: well not that i removed this, it tells me : uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null, do you have any ideas on how i could fix this?

Comment: Are you ever actually adding the formtable to the DOM? Is it possible that the id `tablemc` doesn't actually exist, and therefore cannot add the table to it?

Comment: Yes, tablemc does exist, as my table shows up perfectly. Link of my server even changes to the form quantity like a form would usually do, it just seems like my javascript code doesn't see my form, like the code has run before the form was put in place.

Comment: You said that you removed the code, but i think you may have misunderstood what i was saying in my answer. I will update the answer to show you exactly what i meant

Comment: This now doesn't give me any errors and a line appears in my console, but it is empty. I feel like I have a problem with my input tag but i don't know where EDIT: i got it to work by setting quantity as a var equals to the id of my input